# Fixed pivot header item?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I use pivot create menu (with 4 item). I want FIXED header 4 item (not move) and change image item header when I move item (same menu facebook on wp8)
This is my code

```
{<phone:Pivot Height="758" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Loaded="Pivot_Loaded_2" UnloadedPivotItem="Pivot_UnloadedPivotItem">
<phone:Pivot.Background>
    <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="bg_login_popup_head.png"/>
</phone:Pivot.Background>

<phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Image Source="{Binding}" Height="83" Width="94" />
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>


<!--Pivot item one-->
<phone:PivotItem x:Name="item1" Header = "/Resources/Icon/ic_home_actionbar_red.png" Margin="0,10,0,0" Foreground="#FF19DE84">
    <phone:PivotItem.Background>
        <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="background.png"/>
    </phone:PivotItem.Background>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="157" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="337" Margin="61,422,0,0" FontSize="50" Text="Đoi mih mot chut nhe" Foreground="#FFD68F8B"/>
</phone:PivotItem>

<!--Pivot item two-->
<phone:PivotItem Header="/Resources/Icon/ic_love_actionbar_red.png" Margin="0,10,0,-37" >
    <phone:PivotItem.Background>
        <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="background.png"/>
    </phone:PivotItem.Background>
</phone:PivotItem>

<phone:PivotItem Header="/Resources/Icon/ic_profile_actionbar_red.png" Margin="0,28,0,0">
    <phone:PivotItem.Background>
        <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="background.png"/>
    </phone:PivotItem.Background>
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this is what you're looking for?

[Tabbed interface with Pivot animation for Windows Phone](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Tabbed_interface_with_Pivot_animation_for_Windows_Phone)